# Eric 6 Python IDE Qt version Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, linux-mint, eric-ide

I want to setup Eric 6 IDE on Linux Mint 17.1. I downloaded source code of Eric 6 and I tried to setup.

```
sudo python3 install.py
```

I got an Qt version error on the below.

```
Checking dependencies
Python Version: 3.4.0
Found PyQt5
Found QScintilla2
Found QtGui
Found QtNetwork
Found QtPrintSupport
Found QtSql
Found QtSvg
Found QtWebKit
Found QtWebKitWidgets
Found QtWidgets
Sorry, you must have Qt version 4.8.0 or better or 5.3.0 or better.
```

But when I controlled QT version on my computer. Output is on the below.

```
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.4.0 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/lib
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: What is the output of `python3 -c 'from PyQt5 import QtCore; print(QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR)'`?

Comment: Nothing. Just displayed '>' character.

Comment: You missed off the final quote. Try again: it will always print the version if you do it properly. The point of asking you to do this is to establish which version of Qt that PyQt5 was compiled against (which may not be the same as the one you currently have installed).